# How to load balance between two VMs but only one VM is running at a time?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to create two VMs on Azure. Put them in an Availability Set, run one of them, and if - for some reason - this machine has crashed, to start the other one automatically and forward traffic to it.

What is the best yet simple way to do this with Azure?

Thanks!
ASH

Answer (score 0):

You can use Traffic Manager and configure Priority traffic-routing method 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-routing-methods/#wriority-traffic-routing-method